# Preferred technology to expose a management interface for Windows servers?

Tags: windows, windows-services, wmi

I contribute to a cluster of C++ and C# servers that publish data statistics, connection status, and management commands for use by a management client.  The current implementation uses custom middleware.

Code for both the servers and the client can be changed.  I am considering migration to some standard management solution to simplify the code and improve stability.  The potential to use 3rd party tools would also be a plus.

What technology should I use for the management interface ... WMI?  It seems to be the default, but I don't see a lot of current books or articles.  Or should I expose some common web service?  Or?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that the answers really depends on the scope of you project.

If you target a Microsoft Windows only client server platform, you can plan to instrument your server code and build a WMI provider. WMI comes from a standard (WBEM) but it's for Microsoft usage only. However using WMI, you keep the ability to use open source management tools like Nagios. And on your client machine your server state stay queryable from PowerShell or VBScript.

If you target a mixt Windows Linux client server platform, I think that SNMP (yes this old stuff) still stay in the race, you can plan to instrument your server code and build an SNMP proxy server. This is not so hard on Windows box. This solution open a wide amount of client management tools on any platform.

I would use a web service only if the scope is private use, you develop the management client for your servers tools, but as far as I know Web service is not so standard as far as management is concern.

Answer (score 1):

A web service interface would be how I'd do it. This really decouples server from the client and allows you the ability to use many different types of applications on the client-side to communicate with the server. Utilizing WMI within the services would also be part of going this route. WMI is a bit confusing at first, but offers the greatest amount of flexibility. There are also several libraries that can be used to abstract your code from the nitty-gritty of WMI and see it as a control layer.